# AS3/Air drawing slows down over time

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I have an Air app written in AS3 using FlashDevelop that involves using the `graphics.drawEllipse` method to draw 96 ellipses on the stage each frame (20fps), updating their position and alpha. After a second or so they fade out and are removed.

```
graphics.clear();
graphics.beginFill( color, timer );
graphics.lineStyle( 0, color, timer );
graphics.drawEllipse( x, y, r, r );         
graphics.endFill();
```

The first 7 or so times these groups of 96 ellipses are spawned, they flow very smoothly across the screen as intended. After that they start to stutter like it's a framerate issue.

They are the only moving part in the scene and so are the only visible sign the system is struggling to draw them, but I am aware they may be the symptom rather than the cause of the slowdown. I have used the profiler and believe I have eliminated all the memory leaks.

I am wondering if anyone can see a problem with what I'm doing, or if not has any other suggestions with what could be causing the slowdown (I guess just general as3 things that could cause it).

Comment: Check if you properly remove old ellipses both from display list and from internal references, including event listeners.

Comment: It turns out the problem was a TextField being updated every frame (being set to the same text). Once I removed that it was all good. Thanks for the tip though.